# Convert UTC date to oracle Date

Tags: oracle, date

I have a string in this format: `"2013-06-05T19:41:12.739"` and I need to convert it to a date field in this format: `"2013-06-05 19:41:12"`

How can I do this with Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use to_date() or to_timestamp() to convert a string literal to a date/timestamp value:

If you need the milliseconds you have to convert it into a timestamp, otherwise (if you want to discard the milliseconds) you can convert it into a date:

```
select to_timestamp('2013-06-05T19:41:12.739', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3')
from dual;
```

To get rid of the milliseconds, simply cast the result from the above statement to a `DATE`

```
select cast(to_timestamp('2013-06-05T19:41:12.739', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3') as date)
from dual;
```

---

> *I need to convert it to a date field in this format:*

A `DATE` column **does *NOT* have a "format"**.

You apply a format to a `DATE` column when you *display* it. Either explicitely by using `to_char()` or implicitely by the NLS settings in effect (or by some code in your application).

Comment: So I am basically specifying how the date is coming in, and not how the date is going to look in the date field?

Comment: @Bagzli: correct. Internally the date is (basically) stored as numbers for day/month/year/...

Comment: Thank you, I had thought it was the other way around.  Thanks for explaining it.